# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta este programa en Java?

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en programación y no ejecuta el programa, no se si hay algo mal.

> Programa en Java que pida por medio de ventana (JOptionPane), la
> cantidad de elementos a ingresar, y por medio de consola (Scanner)
> capturar el nombre y la edad de niños entre 5 y 12 años, una vez
> capturados los datos deberán imprimirse de menor a mayor (ascendente)
> y de mayor a menor (descendente), con el texto: "El niño de nombre
> Carlos tiene 6 años de edad.

Esto es lo que hice, no tiene errores pero tampoco se ejecuta

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ninosorden {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner ingreso = new Scanner (System.in);
        int arreglo[], nElementos,min,aux;
        String nombre[];
        String aux2;
        nElementos= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE NINOS A REGISTRAR"));
        arreglo = new int [nElementos];
        nombre=new String[nElementos];
        //CAPTURA DE LOS NOMBRES Y EDADES
        System.out.println("===============CAPTURA DE NOMBRES Y EDADES=============== ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nElementos; i++) {
            do {
                System.out.println((1+i)+" nombre: ");
                nombre[i] = ingreso.next();
                System.out.print((i+1)+"edad "+": ");
                arreglo[i] = ingreso.nextInt();
                if (arreglo[i]<5||arreglo[i]>12){
                    System.out.println("solo se pueden ingresar datos entre 6 y 12 anos");
                }
            }while (arreglo[i]<5||arreglo[i]>12);
        }
        //ALGORITMO DE ORDENAMIENTO POR SELECCION
        for (int i = 0; i < nElementos; i++) {
            min = i;
            for (int j = i+1; j < nElementos; j++) {
                if (arreglo[j] < arreglo[min]) {
                    min=j;
                }
            }
            aux = arreglo[i];
            aux2= nombre[i];
            arreglo[i]=arreglo[min];
            nombre[i]=nombre[min];
            arreglo[min]=aux;
            nombre[min]=aux2;
        }
        System.out.print("\nOrden ascendente...\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < nElementos; i++) {
            System.out.println(nombre[i]+" Tiene "+arreglo[i]+" años");
        }
        System.out.print("\nOrden Descendente...\n");
        for (int i = nElementos-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
            System.out.println(nombre[i]+" Tiene "+arreglo[i]+" años");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso realiza el [tour], una pregunta que es solamente el enunciado de una tarea sin mayores detalles o aclaraciones termina cerrada

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado/intentado?

Comment: si, perdonen, ya subí el código, gracias

Comment: ¿Aquí cuál es la pregunta realmente? ¿Que resultado obtienes? ¿Obtienes algún error?

Comment: Pues sí que corre tu programa (lo acabo de probar) y hace lo que debe. Posiblemente tenga que ver con la configuración de tu editor, tu entorno o algo similar. **¿Cómo estás intentando correrlo?** || PD. Muy llamativo que pidas el número de niños con un formulario gráfico y el resto por consola

Answer (score 0):

En tu `JOptionPane` te está faltando el primer parámetro que es el elemento padre que ejecuta el cuadro de dialogo.

Como en este caso no hay un botón o algo que dispare el cuadro de dialogo ponle `null` como parámetro.

```java
nElementos= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"INGRESE EL NUMERO DE NINOS A REGISTRAR"));
```